# How does Linux command 'tree' sort by file type?

Tags: linux, sorting

I can't find such sorting option in "tree --help"

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I don't think `tree` supports it, but it'd be a nice addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux doesn't support to sort file by type. Please have a look at the [tree](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) documentation.

Have a look at the following [answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/19781/how-to-make-ls-sort-by-file-extension-and-then-name) on how you can use `sort` command instead to sort by file type.